# Services “istio-pilot” not found, when trying “Shared control plane (multi-network)” on EKS 1.14

Tags: istio, amazon-eks

Background: 2 x AWS EKS Kubernetes stack, version 1.14, Platform version eks.9

I’m following [this guide](https://istio.io/docs/setup/install/multicluster/shared-gateways/#setup-cluster-2) to setup "Shared control plane (multi-network)", got these errors when doing “Setup cluster 2”.

Any tips? Thanks!

```
  $ istioctl manifest apply --context=$CTX_CLUSTER2 \
  --set profile=remote \
  --set values.gateways.enabled=true \
  --set values.security.selfSigned=false \
  --set values.global.createRemoteSvcEndpoints=true \
  --set values.global.remotePilotCreateSvcEndpoint=true \
  --set values.global.remotePilotAddress=${LOCAL_GW_ADDR} \
  --set values.global.remotePolicyAddress=${LOCAL_GW_ADDR} \
  --set values.global.remoteTelemetryAddress=${LOCAL_GW_ADDR} \
  --set values.gateways.istio-ingressgateway.env.ISTIO_META_NETWORK="network2" \
  --set values.global.network="network2" \
  --set values.global.multiCluster.clusterName=${CLUSTER_NAME}

- Applying manifest for component Base...
2020-03-13T14:11:19.644688Z error   installer   error running kubectl: exit status 1
✘ Finished applying manifest for component Base.
- Applying manifest for component Pilot...
✔ Finished applying manifest for component Pilot.
2020-03-13T14:11:29.235035Z error   installer   Failed to wait for resource: resources not ready after 10m0s: services "istio-pilot" not found

- Applying manifest for component IngressGateways...
✔ Finished applying manifest for component IngressGateways.

Component Base - manifest apply returned the following errors:
Error: error running kubectl: exit status 1



✘ Errors were logged during apply operation. Please check component installation logs above.

Error: failed to apply manifests: errors were logged during apply operation
```

P.S. the way I created 2 x EKS clusters, i.e. cluster1 and cluster2

```
$ eksctl create cluster \
–name cluster1 \
–region us-east-1 \
–nodegroup-name standard-workers \
–node-type t3.medium \
–nodes 2 \
–nodes-min 1 \
–nodes-max 3 \
–ssh-access \
–ssh-public-key eks \
–managed
```

Comment: Hi, what istio version is that?

Comment: @PiotrMalec istio-1.5.0

Comment: have you tried with Istio 1.6.0? Maybe they solved the issue

Answer (score 0):

This might be caused by changes introduced in istio `1.5.0`.

According to [istio](https://istio.io/news/releases/1.5.x/announcing-1.5/upgrade-notes/#multicluster-setup) documentation:

> ### Multicluster setup
>
> We recommend that you  **do not upgrade**  to Istio 1.5.0 if you are using a multicluster setup.
>
> Istio 1.5.0 multicluster setup has several known issues ([27102](https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/21702),  [21676](https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/21676)) that make it unusable in both shared control plane and replicated control plane deployments. These issues will be resolved in Istio 1.5.1.